# Subversion - command line update

Tags: svn

What would be the subversion command line statement to update to the latest revision of the code in the repository?

I have the code already checked out, but I need to update to the latest code since some of the files have been updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command is

```
svn update
```

or

```
svn up
```

for short.

See [the SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html).